# Alterar a cor do "placeholder" sem afectar a cor do "value"

Tags: html5, css3, cross-browser, placeholder

Em HTML5, podemos fazer uso do atributo [**`placeholder`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-placeholder) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> com vista a dar ao utilizador uma dica sobre o tipo de dados que determinado campo aceita.

Para evitar confusões entre dados realmente escritos pelo utilizador e o texto com as instruções, gostaria de aplicar uma cor distinta ao texto do `placeholder`.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Primeiro e Último nome apenas" value="John Doe">
<!--               └────────────────────┬────────────────────┘ └──────┬───────┘  
                                   color: #ccc                   color: #444
-->
```

## Pergunta

Recorrendo apenas a CSS, como podemos definir a cor para o `placeholder` sem afectar a cor definida para o `value` numa maneira que funcione nos diversos navegadores ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Você precisa usar propriedades não-padrão do CSS para afetar somente o placeholder:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: red;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: red;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: red;  
}
```

<sup>Solução encontrada no site [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/)</sup>

Isso deve funcionar em todos os browsers modernos. O IE suporta [o atributo](http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder) `placeholder` e [a pseudo-classe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `:-ms-input-placeholder` a partir da versão 10.

Answer (score 8):

```
input,
textarea {
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 70%;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: orange;
   font: 12px verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
   color: orange;
   font: 12px verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
   color: orange;  
   font: 12px verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: orange;  
   font: 12px verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}
```