# Estilizar Placeholder

Tags: jquery

```
if ($("#nome").val() === ""){
    $("#nome::placeholder").css("color", "red");
    $("#nome").focus();
    return false;
}
```

Meu objetivo é **setar** a cor do **placeholder** para **vermelho** caso o **campo nome** **esteja** vazio

Segui esse exemplo

http://jsfiddle.net/erackson/9kaHw/2/

Mas não funcionou.

Onde estou errando?

Obs.: O **focus** funciona mas o **placeholder** não fica **vermelho**

Comment: Cara, mas se o campo não está vazio como vc quer que apareça o placeholder, se vc digitar um . que seja no input o placeholde já some...

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Alterar a cor do "placeholder" sem afectar a cor do "value"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8281/alterar-a-cor-do-placeholder-sem-afectar-a-cor-do-value)

Comment: no caso é quando submete o formulário que a verificação e feita. Da forma da resposta que postei, resolve o problema!

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($("#nome").val() === ""){
    $("#nome").addClass("red").focus();
    return false;
}
```

Criei uma classe